# Johnson homomorphism image of a Dehn twist about a separating simple closed curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, mapping-class-group

So this is from Benson Farb's text and I need clarification on his explanation.

[image]

[image]

**QUESTION**: So my first question is why is $\gamma \in \Gamma'$, where $\Gamma=\pi_1(S_g^1)$. My second question is why does $[\gamma,x]\in[\Gamma',\Gamma]$ implies that $[\gamma,x]=0\in \wedge^2H$. And why does this imply that $\tau(T_c(x))=0$ where $\tau$ is the Johnson homomorphism.

**EDIT**: My apologies for the typo. It should have said $\Gamma=\pi_1$ not $\Gamma'$. Also $H=H_1(S_g^1)$.

Comment: I think $\Gamma'$ is meant to be the commutator subgroup of $\Gamma=\pi_1(S_g^1)$. Then $\gamma\in\Gamma'$ by Hurewitz theorem. As for your second question, you should explain what $H$ is.

Comment: Can you explain why Hurewitz theorem implies that $\gamma\in\Gamma'$? Is it because it doesn't commute with the standard generators for $H_1$? I just don't see why $\gamma$ being a separating simple closed curve implies its zero when when project it to $H_1$ using the Huremicz homomorphism.

Comment: Every separating simple loop (in case of at most one boundary component of your surface) is nul homologous. (Just use the definition of say simplicial, homology.)

Comment: Ahh okay. I see. Thanks. Do you have any comments on my second question in my original post? In other words why does $[\gamma,x]\in [\Gamma,\Gamma']$ imply that $[\gamma,x]=0\in\wedge^2H$?

Comment: What is $H$ in the question?

Comment: $H=H_1(S_g^1)$.